# ADO.NET how to use parameter in dataset?

Tags: c#, ado.net

[image: dbDataSet]

Where i need initialize parameter, for when form will open, to make it work?

Query:

```
SELECT id, id_work, name FROM ttz WHERE (id_work = @idwork)
```

I want @idwork value = textBox1.Text

I did this :

```
private void frmTTZ_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ttzTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbDataSet.ttz,Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
}
```

Comment: Are you using a typed DataSet which autogenerates the update statements? Your image suggests this since it contains the TableAdapters. If this is true i don't understand the question.

Comment: Are you using a typed DataSet which autogenerates the update statements? Yes. When i open form, i want do query with my parameter.

Comment: And i don't know where i can initialize him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a typed DataSet which autogenerates the update statements? Your image suggests this since it contains the TableAdapters.

> Yes. When i open form, i want do query with my parameter.

Then all is already there. You only have to create an instance of `ttzTableAdapter` and call the `GetData` or the `Fill` method.

```
var da = new ttzTableAdapter();
ttz tbl = da.GetData(textBox1.Text);
```

or by passing a ttz-table:

```
var tbl = new ttz();
da.Fill(tbl, textBox1.Text);
```

[MSDN: `TableAdapters` - Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt3ycf2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Johnny: If it does not see it, it's probably in another namespace. So use that namespace. If you aren't sure, look into the autogenerated files to see in which namespace these classes are.

Answer (score 0):

If "ttz" is a TableAdapter then

var result = ttzTableAdapter.GetData(textBox1.Text);

Hope this helps